# Modify Local Security Policy (registry/powershell/other)

Tags: security, powershell, registry, windows-10

I am creating our Windows 10 image and found that if I set the Local Security policy to require a complex password with a minimum password length greater than 0, I can't boot to the desktop after running Sysprep.

I would like to disable the complexity and length requirements in the image, but have then added automatically, via some kind of script. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not using group policy for this?

Comment: Good question. In this case, the image will be used for workgroup machines, deployed to customer sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting the following into my Windows answer file

```
Secedit /configure /db secedit.sdb /cfg c:\it\localAccountPolicy.inf
```